# How to add CSS only to the options page of a plugin in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I want to add a stylesheet for the options_page of my plugin only. But how to do that? My code so far:

```
function add_options_page_style() {
    wp_register_style('options_page_style', plugins_url('css/options_style.css',__FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('options_page_style');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_options_page_style' );
```

I could place an if statement before the line with `add_action...` but I'm not sure how to filter my options page. I already tried the `$pagename` variable and also this line: `$wp_query->queried_object->post_name;` but it didn't work.

The filter `$_GET['page']` does work but might break in future versions.

Comment: Did you tried to copy the example code: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style#Load_stylesheet_only_on_a_plugin.27s_options_page and modify it to your paths and function names?

Comment: Oh thx for that link, seems to be helpful. I googled but didn't find anything like that. But I could solve my problem with adding an if statement with $_GET['page'] before adding the styles.

Comment: Your "solution" (or better call it a "hack") could work for current version of the WP, but when WP moves from 3.8 to 3.9 or 4.x, then you could have a bug! Better stay the way described in the docs! ;-)

Comment: @user2718671 Just as note, don't edit the question to mark as solved; post your own solution as an *answer*, where you can mark it as solved - thus keeps it line with how SO operates :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere you'll be registering page like this:-

```
function register_page(){
    global $page_hook_suffix;
    $page_hook_suffix = add_options_page('Your_plugin', 'Your_plugin', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'display_form');
}    
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_page');
```

And while enqueueing script you'll do something like this:-

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    global $page_hook_suffix;
    if( $hook != $page_hook_suffix )
        return;        
    wp_register_style('options_page_style', plugins_url('css/options_style.css',__FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('options_page_style');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Comment: thanks. I used add_menu_page instead of add_options_page but after inserting the page hook it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style($hook) {
    // Load only on ?page=mypluginname
    if($hook != 'toplevel_page_mypluginname') {
            return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', plugins_url('admin-style.css', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

add your page slug as suffix to `toplevel_page_` 
e.g. if page slug is this-plugin-options
then

```
if($hook != 'toplevel_page_this-plugin-options') {
  return;
}
```

here is [wordpress doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) with 
Example: Load CSS File on All Admin Pages, 
Example: **Load CSS File from a plugin on specific Admin Page**